# Timing Chain Tensioner Assembly Life Expectancy - 2003 Corolla

Tags: toyota, corolla, belt-tensioner

Question about the tensioner assembly for my 2003 Corolla.  At 99,000 miles Toyota replaced the assembly.  This week, after a routine inspection, the same Toyota service shop suggested replacing the tensioner (leakage, according to the advisor) *and* timing cover gasket.  At a much higher cost, of course.  My Corolla now has 116,000 miles.  Should I expect the tensioner to need replacing at 17,000 miles?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've seen to problems with the tensioner assembly is oil leaking:

http://www.paulstravelpictures.com/Toyota-Corolla-Timing-Chain-Tensioner-Oil-Leak-Repair-Guide/

If the Toyota service shop already repaired it, I would have a conversation with the manager about what he/she thinks they might have done wrong during the first repair to make the second repair necessary.

Comment: Could simply be a defective part.  I had a factory Toyota radiator hose let go (internal delamination) just a few weeks after install.  Those things happen.  Hopefully there's a warranty...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like nonsense. My corolla has 170 k on it and no problems with the tensioner. I know you asked this question a long time ago but new readers may benefit.

Comment: Benefit from what?